# How do I change the join character in Vim?

Tags: vim

In Vim, one can join two lines by typing capital J. 
However, these are usually joined by a space.

I seem to remember there was a way to change the character used for the joining by setting some variable, but I can't seem to find it again.

I'd appreciate it if anyone could remind me, or confirm that it can't be done.

Comment: In response to the two close votes, the faq states that questions that cover " software tools commonly used by programmers" are on topic. Therefore this question should not be closed as off topic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When I want to join just a few lines I use a 3 keys combo (normal mode):

```
Jr,
```

being `,` the joining character.

In case I want to join more lines or even join lines in groups, I use the previous combo with a macro.

For example, to transform 3 lines in a 3 columns CSV table, I record this macro (assigned to letter `j` of course):

```
qjJr,Jr,jq
```

So, using `@j` joins 3 lines using `,` and goes to the next line.

`10@j` converts 10 lines.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't a setting that allows you to do this directly, see:

```
:help J
```

in particular, the text below the list of commands.

A couple of ways you could do this:

```
:nnoremap J gJi.<ESC>
" or
let joinchar = ';'
nnoremap J :s/\n/\=joinchar/<CR>
```

The latter option allows you to change it on the fly by changing the joinchar option.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this in your .vimrc:

`nnoremap Y Jxi*<Esc>`

It'll remap Y to join the lines with a `*`.

Answer (score 0):

From http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Remap_join_to_merge_comment_lines

put this in your .vimrc:

```
function! JoinWithLeader(count, leaderText)
  let l:linecount = a:count
  " default number of lines to join is 2
  if l:linecount < 2
    let l:linecount = 2
  endif
  echo l:linecount . " lines joined"
  " clear errmsg so we can determine if the search fails
  let v:errmsg = ''

  " save off the search register to restore it later because we will clobber
  " it with a substitute command
  let l:savsearch = @/

  while l:linecount > 1
    " do a J for each line (no mappings)
    normal! J
    " remove the comment leader from the current cursor position
    silent! execute 'substitute/\%#\s*\%('.a:leaderText.'\)\s*/ /'
    " check v:errmsg for status of the substitute command
    if v:errmsg=~'Pattern not found'
      " just means the line wasn't a comment - do nothing
    elseif v:errmsg!=''
      echo "Problem with leader pattern for JoinWithLeader()!"
    else
      " a successful substitute will move the cursor to line beginning,
      " so move it back
      normal! ``
    endif
    let l:linecount = l:linecount - 1
  endwhile
  " restore the @/ register
  let @/ = l:savsearch
endfunction

nnoremap <space> :<C-U>call JoinWithLeader(v:count, '"')<CR>
```

This also allows you to remap J to something else.

Answer (score 0):

It will quicker if you replace the end of line with a comma (or join character)

```
:%s/$/,
```

and then joining multiple lines either by providing a range, or by selecting lines in visual mode and using the join command

```
10J
```

Answer (score -3):

It's mapping. You can read the tutorial in vim wikia : 
[Mapping keys in vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_%28Part_1%29)

Try the command below in command mode, and try to press . This should work :)

```
:map <space> J
```

Comment: I feel like there should be something less general than that.

Comment: You've misunderstood the question. It's not asking to change which key to press to invoke the line-joining command. It's asking to control which character is inserted between the joined lines.